# complex analysis: assume $\lim\limits_{|z|\to+\infty} zf(z)=1$, prove $f(z)=1/z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Proposition.** Let $f$ be a complex analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. If $z\mapsto zf(z)$ is an entire function and $\lim\limits_{|z|\to+\infty} zf(z)=1$ then for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\},f(z)=1/z$.

I have no idea what theorem to use. It is a complex analysis question. Can any one give a hit or indicate how to start this question? Thank you!

Comment: I assume that you mean that $|z|$ tends to infinity. Have you tried using Liouville's theorem? That should work wonders.

Comment: That theorem rocks.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you have a function $h(z)$ that is holomorphich on all of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $$\big|h(z)\big| \xrightarrow{|z| \rightarrow \infty} \text{some constant $k$}$$
than Liouville's theorem tells you that $h(z) \equiv k$.

Try to apply this idea to $h(z) := zf(z)$.

**Additional information**

What follows is overkill but it may be of interest.

Fix some $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\big|z f(z)\big| \xrightarrow{|z| \rightarrow \infty}1$ there exists $r > 0$ such that for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| > r$ we have
$$ 1- \varepsilon < \big|zf(z)\big| < 1+ \varepsilon.$$

Now consider the disk $$\overline{D}(0, r):= \big\{ w \in \mathbb{C} :~ |w| \leq r \big\}.$$
Since $zf(z)$ is entire, it is - in particular - continuous on the disk $\overline{D}(0, r)$. But this disk is compact. Therefore $zf(z)$ reaches a maximum  on $\overline{D}(0, r)$. Let $M> 0$ be this maximum.

We have shown that $\big|zf(z)\big| \leq \max\big\{ 1 + \varepsilon, M\big\}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I just noted that you mentioned that $zf(z)$ is entire. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I have thought about Liouville's theorem, however I am not sure if zf(z) is bounded or not. So is it true that lim zf(z)=1 as z goes to infinity indicate that zf(z) is bounded?

Comment: zf(z) must be bounded since it is entire and tends towards 1 as |z| tends towards infinity (If zf(z) is unbounded in some bounded region, then zf(z) cannot be holomorphic in that region).

Comment: Convergence to 1 as $z$ goes to infinity means that for all $\varepsilon$ there is some $K$ such that if $z > K$ then $zf(z)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of 1. Now we just have to bound $zf(z)$ in the circle $\{ |z| \leq K\}$...

Comment: All right, I got it. Thank you guys.